# Javascript createElement not scanned by Angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I created a new DOM element in the script tags

```
$( "#droppable_home" ).droppable({
 ....
 drop:
  //Create the new widget element. This renders in my page in Chrome's inspect view.
  var obj = document.createElement('widget');
  obj.id = "draggable_button";
  obj.style.cssText = 'position: absolute;left: 35%;top: 50%;';
  $("#droppable_home").parent().append(obj);
 ..........
});
```

My angular directive to scan "widget" elements is below

```
.directive('widget', function($compile) {
 var show = function(scope, element, attrs) {
 var render = function() {  
  alert('Found '+element.attr('id'));   
  if(element.attr('id') === 'draggable_button'){
   alert('placing widget');
   element.html('<div id="widget_button" class="button button-positive" unbindable><span ng-bind="widgetname"></span></div>');
   $compile(element.contents())(scope);
  }
 };

scope.$watch('drag', function(newValue, oldValue) {
   alert('drag changed');
   if(newValue > 0) render();
});

};

return {
  restrict : 'E',
  link : show
 };
})
```

Problem -- the element created above using jQuery is never recognized by the Angular Directive. 
Would be great to know what's missing.

Comment: Sorry i initially commented out the $compile in my question but have now edited the question. Does not work even with the $compile. Have i missed something in the $compile statement?

Comment: i meant use $compile, instead of document.createElement.

Comment: The `obj` has be compiled and linked against a scope before, the directive can trigger, which means your compile code should be part of dynamically injected html, not your directive definition.

Comment: Javascript createElement is called from inside a jQuery "drop" callback. How do i link it to Angular scope in such a case?

Comment: @NoypiGilas moved the javascript inside my controller as $compile-d HTML and that does the job! How do i mark the answer as closed?

Comment: i also have another solution below if you are not inside a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using document.createElement, try the one below: 
- the element.id is the id of the element where you put the "ng-app"

```
var el = angular.element( document.getElementById("element.id") );

var scope = el.scope();
var injector = el.injector();

var $compile = injector.get("$compile");

var mynewel = $compile("<div widget></div>")(scope)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am keeping the controller for now and will revisit this.